# Angular Filter Resets Only On UI

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to filter an array of results when routing to another page in Angular.

It works at first and then filters the results, but at some point the interface results.

I've logged the results, and they stay the same, for some reason it's like the filter resets only on the interface. I've also logged every time my filter function is called, and it's not being called when it resets.

However, when I put:

```
   alert(filter);
```

The filter works as it should and does not reset, even after the alert.

I know this is a vague question with not a lot of code, but I have several directives so it could get complicated. I'm just wondering how it could possibly only be resetting on the UI that doesn't happen when I put an alert in?

**EDIT**

I'm still debugging this, but I'm watching my Network tab in the chrome developer tools. When I have the alert, my script is "667fcdb5.scripts.js" but when I do not have alert my script is "abf5e3ed.script.js". I'm using grunt to build and minify my code. I've built it multiple times to watch the names and it has happened every time. Why would an alert cause a different name?

Comment: When an `alert` fixes your code it usually points to there being an issue with timing of asychronous events.

Comment: @tasseKATT Thanks so much! This was indeed the issue. If you want to add the answer, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: You are welcome :) I think it's better if you write a short answer yourself describing the situation.